# Not able to initialize Namespace Manager in Powershell

Tags: powershell

When I am initializing the Namespace manager, I am getting an error message that the constructor was not found.

I am trying to run `$XmlNSManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager -ArgumentList $xml.NameTable` and received below error:

```
New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager.
At line:1 char:17
+ ... NSManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager -ArgumentList $ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

```
$XmlNSManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager -ArgumentList $xml.NameTable
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `$xml.NameTable` ? Please edit your question